# Meteor Bootstrap grid system not working

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

//edited: simplified version now

I am using meteor and want to use a bootstrap grid system in my templates. Unfortunately it just displays the two columns on top of each other as if no bootstrap class was assigned to them at all. I would expect them to be next to each other on the same line

I haven't installed any bootstrap package. (I had but uninstalled it to be sure it is not that) I have only installed other basic standard packages like the facebook login or autoform

Bootstrap itself is working because autoform is styled with it and the alert classes are working in my template for example

There is no other css styling at all in this template yet

The HTML must be well formed as meteor would not render the template otherwise

I tried:

- installing the twbs:bootstrap package
- installing the mizzao:bootstrap-3 package instead
- using more complex bootstrap with container-fluid

which didn't change anything

Bootstrap is installed in the head tag using the code from this link (MaxCDN):
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

this is the entire code for the template

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">col1</div><div class="col-md-6">col2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As I am very new to bootstrap I assume its a very stupid beginners' issue but I just cannot find it

Comment: `col` is not a Bootstrap 3 class. What happened when you used `col-md-6` instead? Also, verify the exact Bootstrap version.

Comment: I go the code from the official bootstrappage
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#equal-width

it does not work with col-md-6 as well

I am using Bootstrap3

Comment: `col-md-6` will work in Bootstrap 3. `col` will work in Bootstrap 4. Maybe try a minimal example using container > row > col-md-6.

Comment: @ZimSystem: Thanks for your time and help. I created an absolute minimal template now and uninstalled the bootstrap package to link it manually in the header so I know for sure I have the version 3.3.7

`<template name="bstest">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">col1</div><div class="col-md-6">col2</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>`

Still the divs appear on top of each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I figured it out!
It seems to have to do with the relatively small size of my screen plus that my developer console was opened. When I used col-xs-6 it worked.
Thanks Anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap grid system has four classes: xs (phones), sm (tablets), md (desktops), and lg (larger desktops). The classes can be combined to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-7></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-5"></div>
</div>
```